# Explicit XAML style doesn't get applied for certain properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In LogOnView.xaml:

```
<controls:FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard
    Style="{StaticResource TouchScreenKeyboardStyle}"
    x:Name="TouchKeyboard"
    Placement="Bottom"               <--- Only gets applied if I put this here
    VerticalOffset="-300"            <--- Only gets applied if I put this here
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

In Styles.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="TouchScreenKeyboardStyle"  TargetType="controls:FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard">
    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="355"/>
    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom"/>     <--- No effect
    <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="-300"/>  <--- No effect
    <Setter Property="AreAnimationsEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="IsAllowedToFade" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="MaximumKeyboardOpacity" Value="1.0"/>
    <Setter Property="MinimumKeyboardOpacity" Value="1.0"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
</Style>
```

Why are the Placement and VerticalOffset properties not applied when I define them the TouchScreenKeyboardStyle style? All the other properties work fine.

Comment: Perhaps these properties are initialized in the FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard's constructor? Then they would get local property values, which have higher precedence than values from Style setters.

Comment: TargetType should be TargetType ={x:Type controls:FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard}.

Comment: @HeenaPatil No, that is not necessary. It works without `{x:Type ...}` since quite a while (don't know the exact WPF version).

Comment: Just a random guess, remove x:Key="TouchScreenKeyboardStyle" from style and remove Style="{StaticResource TouchScreenKeyboardStyle}".

Comment: Are those properties bound in the default style template with TemplateBinding?